# Comparing old and new observer values but if function is not working as expected

Tags: objective-c

I've got 2 fade methods that simply change the background of a textfield. The only difference is the image used for the background. The names of the images have been copied and pasted so there's no spelling errors.

```
- (IBAction)fadeEnable:(UITextField *)textField;
{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
[textField setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_text.png"];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
[textField setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction)fadeDisable:(UITextField *)textField;
{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
[textField setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_text_2"];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
[textField setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I have an observer on my textField which looks to see if the "enabled@ property has been changed.

I'm trying to write a little bit of code that says if the enabled property changes, and it changes to enabled, then run the enabled animation. If it changes to disabled, run the disabled animation.

Unfortunately, it only runs the fadeDisabled method in both scenarios and i have no idea why.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *) context;
{


UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)object;




BOOL new = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
BOOL old = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] boolValue];

NSLog(@"new,%i",new);
NSLog(@"old,%i",old);

if ((new != old) && (new == NO))
{

 [self fadeDisable:txtField];
}

else if ((new != old) && (new == YES))
{
 [self fadeEnable:txtField];
}

}
```

Comment: Check in the debugger (or with a log statement) that the images are found. In particular, your enabled image name has the `.png` extension, but the disabled doesn't; AFAIK that should work unless you only have the @2x, but try removing the .png.

Comment: Not really sure how to do that. I removed the.png, didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught the mistake, for fadeDisabled, i need to change the disabled background, not the normal background.

used the following and it seems to be working fine now.

```
textField.disabledBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_text_2"];
```